# Is it possible to install a setup.exe silently with one click on batch file

Tags: batch-file, ms-office

I am trying to do a silent installation of MS OFFICE setup, without any user interface. Is this possible?

When I was trying to install a share MS OFFICE setup silently with Silent Switch in the `START` command, it was giving me an error message. 
Can anyone help me to proceed further with silent installs?

Below is the command I used:

```
start /wait \\sharepath /quiet or /S
```

Comment: Your command contains no installation package.

Comment: @RGuggisberg, is their any syntax to proceed with silent installation of any setup.exe. I was getting stuck

Answer (score 0):

Instead of jumping right to a completely silent install, perhaps you should try a Basic UI.  There could be popup message boxes, etc that will cause your install to hang if you go completely silent.  You can get help by doing:

```
msiexec /?
```

Then you can launch an msi file with something like this:

```
msiexec /qb /i "Your.msi" %YourCmdLine%
```

You can get a list of arguments for msiexec by:

```
Setup.exe /v"Lp Properties.log"
```

or

```
msiexec /i YourInstaller.msi /Lp Properties.log
```